# How do I get Helvetica font in math snippet in matplotlib?

Tags: math, fonts, matplotlib

I want to write `$\eta=a^2$` in Helvetica/Arial a matplotlib label. I see two possibilities:

1. `u"η${}=a^2$"` with

   ```
   matplotlib.rc("font", **{"sans-serif": ["Arial"], "size": fontsize})
   ```
2. `u"$\\eta=a^2$"` with

   ```
   matplotlib.rc("font", **{"sans-serif": ["Arial"], "size": fontsize})
   matplotlib.rc("text", usetex=True)
   matplotlib.rc("text.latex", preamble=["\\usepackage{helvet}\\usepackage{sfmath}"])
   ```

In the first case, all math has the standard CM fonts.  In the second case, the η is in the standard CM font.  Bummer.  Is there a way to get *everything* in Helvetica/Arial?

Answer (score 0):

In your first option, just add the following to the 'font' dictionary:

```
'style':'normal'
'family':'sans'
```